# how to remove the css overflow:hidden of jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a search input and overlap it on title bar of a jQuery dialog but my problems are:

- I can't remove the css overflow property of this specific jQuery dialog
- The Title bar is always at the top of my input search box.

I've also tried this:

```
 $('div#viewVoters').attr('style','overflow:visible');
 $('#viewVoters').css('overflow','');
 $('#viewVoters').remove('style');
```

Any idea how to remove the css property or any idea how to add a search input to it?

```
<div id="viewVoters" style="width: auto; min-height: 95px; height: auto; overflow: hidden;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just override it in your CSS:

```
#viewVoters {
    overflow: auto !important;  /* or 'visible' whatever */
}
```

Comment: `overflow: unset !important;`

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#viewVoters').css('overflow','visible');
```

this will work for sure 
instead of

```
$('#viewVoters').css('overflow','');
```

Comment: I think this will be $('#viewVoters').css('overflow','visible');

Answer (score -1):

yeah, better to get the specificity right than use !important in a production site.

Remember that one ID is higher than 4 classes and an element...
'#MyID' is stronger than '.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4 p', so you probably need to look a parents to see where else there are ID's.

Comment: I think he's trying to remove inline styles generated by Jquery. That's why I suggested !important